PS recursive function to generate full path
from an API I get the following array of PSobjects
$testgroups

total device_groups
----- -------------
 1062 {@{id=-2ZPmENMTTSmfNxuGd2Emw; name=Server; description=; created=27/06/2024 10:07:39; modified=27/06/2024 10:07:39; parent_id=T5dNIARCR7OnuzW8IIAsWg...},

$testgroups.device_groups[0..2]

id          : -2ZPmENMTTSmfNxuGd2Emw
name        : Server
description : 
created     : 27/06/2024 10:07:39
modified    : 27/06/2024 10:07:39
parent_id   : T5dNIARCR7OnuzW8IIAsWg

id          : -6XA_2FOSZSw5Bk6HXLewQ
name        : SBC
description : 
created     : 27/06/2024 10:07:40
modified    : 27/06/2024 10:07:40
parent_id   : M8ZBfSjGQtamIAJZpVI7Cw

id          : -GaDYTJbSPaid64tWUDQ_A
name        : RT SCOM_GW
description : group for testing
created     : 27/06/2024 10:07:41
modified    : 27/06/2024 10:07:41
parent_id   : CbuM2_KDQ82BBPlS4lx_Mg

As you can see there is a parent_id property which refers to its parent group. the "root" group has the property empty.
I'm wrapping my head around making a recursive function to generate the full path for each groups, but didn't manage to get anything working.
Ideally the format of the new "fullPath" property could look like this : root\subgroup1\subgroup2 for each object

Without looking at the full return from the API, it looks like the result isn't nested and that both parents and children are next to each other. Easiest would probably be to go through each results parent id and look for it in $testgroups.device_groups and storing the results in an Object

In this StackOverflow answer is an example of how you might recursively iterate through an object-graph. If you looking for a of-the-shell solution, you might try this ObjectGraphTools module, which includes cmdlet which let you do things like $TestGroups | Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Leaf. For any formal answer, please add an example of the input ($TestGroups | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99) to your question.

Please provide the input and expected output for an example. I would say an example with a bit more records in it would be useful.

Provide a CSV or JSON sample of the objects in $testgroups.device_groups for testing.

Managed to get it working. Apologies if I wasn't clear enough the demand and explanation.
The goal was to create a new property (fullPathName) that generates a full path for every groups, looking up every parent groups until we hit the root group. For example, we'd have 2 psobjects, one being the "parent" of the other.
$testgroups.device_groups | Where-Object { $_.id -eq "F8S_MJ4tSPi-D_Eoofgo2w" -or $_.id -eq "Fmp5838YRsyElHM27PdZww" }}

id           : F8S_MJ4tSPi-D_Eoofgo2w
name         : subgroup 1
description  : 
created      : 04/07/2024 14:19:00
modified     : 04/07/2024 14:19:00
parent_id    : Fmp5838YRsyElHM27PdZww

id           : Fmp5838YRsyElHM27PdZww
name         : Aurelien policies tests
description  : 
created      : 04/07/2024 14:18:52
modified     : 04/07/2024 14:18:52
parent_id    : gBuOolHrTt64XdEmfRM60A

Following recursive function did the trick
function Get-NameChain {
    param (
        [PSCustomObject]$CurrentGroup,
        [Array]$AllGroups,
        [String]$Chain = ""
    )
    # If the current group is root (no parent_id), prepend its name to the chain.
    if (-not $CurrentGroup.parent_id) {
        if ($Chain -eq "") {
            return $CurrentGroup.name # If chain is empty, it's the root group.
        } else {
            return $CurrentGroup.name + "\" + $Chain # Prepend root name to chain.
        }
    } else {
        # Find the parent group.
        $ParentGroup = $AllGroups | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $CurrentGroup.parent_id }
        if ($ParentGroup) {
            # If there's a parent, prepend the parent's name to the chain and recurse.
            $NewChain = if ($Chain -eq "") { $CurrentGroup.name } else { $CurrentGroup.name + "\" + $Chain }
            return Get-NameChain -CurrentGroup $ParentGroup -AllGroups $AllGroups -Chain $NewChain
        } else {
            # If no parent found (which shouldn't happen), return the current chain.
            return $Chain
        }
    }
}

The following command looped through every group to use the recursive function
$testgroups.device_groups | ForEach-Object {
             $FullNameChain = Get-NameChain -CurrentGroup $_ -AllGroups $testgroups.device_groups -Chain ""
             $_ | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "fullPathName" -NotePropertyValue $FullNameChain -Force               
         }


Below is a non-recursive version - it works by first processing all root items, and then repeatedly iterating over any remaining unprocessed items looking for any that have an immediate parent that we've already processed. It then processes them before looping again until there's no unprocessed items left.
It effectively works its way down the tree structure populating paths by appending the name of each item to the already-calculated full path of its immediate parent.
First, here's some test data:
$device_groups = @"
    [
        {
            "id": "aaa",
            "name": "name-aaa",
            "parent_id": "root"
        },
        {
            "id": "root",
            "name": "name-root",
            "parent_id": null
        },
        {
            "id": "bbb",
            "name": "name-bbb",
            "parent_id": "root"
        },
        {
            "id": "ccc",
            "name": "name-ccc",
            "parent_id": "aaa"
        }
    ]
"@ | convertfrom-json

and the iterative function:
function Add-FullPathName
{
    param( $DeviceGroups )

    # add an empty "fullPathName" property to every item so we don't have to worry
    # about whether it exists or not later in the code
    foreach( $item in $DeviceGroups )
    {
        $item | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "fullPathName" -NotePropertyValue $null
    }

    # initialise an "unprocessed" list with all items - we'll remove items from
    # this when we process them, so when this list is empty we've finished
    $unprocessed = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    $unprocessed.AddRange($DeviceGroups)

    # initialise an empty "processed" loookup hashtable - we'll add items to this
    # by id when we process them, and then we can find them later by id if they're
    # the immediate parent of other items
    $processed = @{}

    # process all the root items
    $roots = $DeviceGroups | where-object { $null -eq $_.parent_id }
    foreach( $root in $roots )
    {
        $root.fullPathName = $root.name
        $unprocessed.Remove($root)
        $processed.Add($root.id, $root)
    }

    # any remaining items must be children - our items *hopefully*
    # form a valid tree structure, but there *could* be a cycle
    # or references to non-existent parents
    while( $unprocessed.Count -gt 0 )
    {

        # process any child items that are *immediate* children of
        # any item we've already processed
        $processed_count = 0
        $index = 0
        while( $index -lt $unprocessed.Count )
        {
            $item = $unprocessed[$index]
            $parent = $processed[$item.parent_id]
            if( $null -eq $parent )
            {
                # we've not processed this item's parent yet,
                # so skip it for now
                $index++
            }
            else
            {
                # we've processed this item's immediate parent
                # so we can process this item now
                $item.fullPathName = $parent.fullPathName + "\" + $item.name
                $unprocessed.Remove($item)
                $processed.Add($item.id, $item)
                $processed_count++
            }
        }

        # did we manage to process any items?
        # if not there's no point looping again as we'll just do the same thing
        if( $processed_count -eq 0 )
        {
            throw "cycle or non-existent parent_id detected"
        }

    }

}

which is called like this:
Add-FullPathName $device_groups

to get the following output:
PS> $device_groups

id   name      parent_id fullPathName
--   ----      --------- ------------
aaa  name-aaa  root      name-root\name-aaa
root name-root           name-root
bbb  name-bbb  root      name-root\name-bbb
ccc  name-ccc  aaa       name-root\name-aaa\name-ccc

By starting with the roots and then only processing immediate children we effectively walk down the tree structure, and we can calculate the full path for each item as the parent's full path plus the child name - we know the parent's full path has already been populated because we found it in the "processed" lookup hashtable.
